# PHP reorder array containing duplicate items to make/keep distance between duplicated items

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, duplicates

Imagine Array with elements -  **Retail, Retail, Entertainment, Entertainment**

I need to sort them so no Duplicate element are next to each other but **overall order can be pretty random** - **Retail, Entertainment, Retail, Entertainment**

I've tried **uasort()**, but cant quit find where to start, as it will compare all possible pairs I think I should like store in external array already sort-checked elements to know in which case  **return - or + integer**, and is it possible to move multiple places aka **return -2;** or smthing in uasort callback

Input array `$input = ['Retail', 'Retail', 'Food', 'Charity', 'Entertainment', 'Entertainment', 'Transport', 'Cosmetics'];`

And Output array should look like `$output = ['Retail', 'Food', 'Retail', 'Charity', 'Entertainment', 'Transport', 'Entertainment', 'Cosmetics'];`

My try:

```php
<?php

$input  = ['Retail', 'Retail', 'Food', 'Charity', 'Entertainment', 'Entertainment', 'Transport', 'Cosmetics'];
$sorted = [];

uasort(
    $input,
    static function ($a, $b) use (&$sorted) {
        $is_a_sorted = in_array($a, $sorted, true);
        $is_b_sorted = in_array($b, $sorted, true);

        switch (true) {
            case !$is_a_sorted && !$is_b_sorted:
                $sorted[] = $a;
                $sorted[] = $b;
                return -1;
            case $is_a_sorted || $is_b_sorted:
                return 1;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
);

print_r($input);
```

which results in:

> Array (
> [7] => Cosmetics
> [4] => Entertainment
> [6] => Transport
> [5] => Entertainment
> [2] => Food
> [3] => Charity
> [0] => Retail
> [1] => Retail )

Comment: I'll add and previous attempt little later...

Comment: Are you determined to get that _specific_ output order, or would _any other_ order that does not have two items with the same name next to each other, also be acceptable? Does as much of the original order as possible need to be preserved, or would, say, the whole output array you have shown in completely opposite order also be acceptable? How do you want to handle things in a situation where you demands _can’t_ be fullfilled, like if the input was [foo, foo, bar, foo]?

Comment: no, order can be random, but would be better if order is kept as close as possible to original order -(minus) duplicates.

Comment: I would call this "shuffling" and not "sorting".  Nearly all sort algorithms compare only 2 items for rank.  This clearly needs to compare more than 2 items.  But, what an interesting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by [this link](https://iq.opengenus.org/rearrange-string-no-same-adjacent-characters/), I've decided to compact the data into an associative array of values and counts, then sort the array from most occurring to least occurring.  I loop through the array and process the first element only.  I add the value to the output array, then decrement its count and move it to the position after the next element.

I have built in a failsafe to prevent an infinite loop when a perfect result is impossible.

If no value occurs more than once, then the loop is never entered.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/M4huo))

```
function valueSeparator(array $array) {
    $maxIterations = count($array);
    $counted = array_count_values($array);
    arsort($counted);
    $iteration = 0;
    $result = [];
    while (max($counted) > 1 && $iteration < $maxIterations) {
        $count = reset($counted);
        $value = key($counted);
        $result[] = $value;
        unset($counted[$value]);
        arsort($counted);
        if ($count > 1) {
            $counted = array_merge(
                array_splice($counted, 0, 1),
                [$value => $count - 1],
                $counted
            );
        }
        ++$iteration;
    }
    array_push($result, ...array_keys($counted));
    var_export($result);
}

foreach ($arrays as $array) {
    valueSeparator($array);
    echo "\n---\n";
}
```

Test Cases:

```
$arrays = [
    ['Retail', 'Retail', 'Food', 'Food', 'Retail'],
    ['Retail', 'Retail', 'Food', 'Charity', 'Entertainment', 'Entertainment', 'Transport', 'Cosmetics'],
    ['Food'],
    ['Retail', 'Retail', 'Food', 'Retail'],
    ['Retail', 'Retail', 'Retail', 'Food', 'Food', 'Food', 'Charity', 'Charity', 'Charity'],
    ['Charity', 'Entertainment', 'Retail', 'Retail' ,'Retail']
];
```

Outputs:

```
array (
  0 => 'Retail',
  1 => 'Food',
  2 => 'Retail',
  3 => 'Food',
  4 => 'Retail',
)
---
array (
  0 => 'Retail',
  1 => 'Entertainment',
  2 => 'Food',
  3 => 'Retail',
  4 => 'Entertainment',
  5 => 'Charity',
  6 => 'Transport',
  7 => 'Cosmetics',
)
---
array (
  0 => 'Food',
)
---
array (
  0 => 'Retail',
  1 => 'Food',
  2 => 'Retail',
  3 => 'Retail',
)
---
array (
  0 => 'Retail',
  1 => 'Food',
  2 => 'Charity',
  3 => 'Retail',
  4 => 'Food',
  5 => 'Charity',
  6 => 'Retail',
  7 => 'Food',
  8 => 'Charity',
)
---
array (
  0 => 'Retail',
  1 => 'Charity',
  2 => 'Retail',
  3 => 'Entertainment',
  4 => 'Retail',
)
---
```

Comment: Bravo, it did well with this: `['Peter', 'Peter', 'Paul', 'Paul', 'Paul']`.

Comment: That's where I was going, but thought edge cases would still trip it.  I was looking for some kind of 'repellent' algo.

Comment: another sidecase: ['Charity', 'Entertainment', 'Retail', 'Retail' ,'Retail']; sory for bothering

Comment: No, not at all a bother.  I appreciate whistleblowing.  I cannot temporarily delete my answer not that it is accepted but I will repair it after dinner/family time.  Cheers @Fat

Comment: @Fat thanks, I added another arsort to correct the logic

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to sort it, maybe anyone has better ideas:

```php
<?php

$array  = ['Retail', 'Retail', 'Food', 'Charity', 'Entertainment', 'Entertainment', 'Transport', 'Cosmetics'];
$sorted = [];

while (!empty($array)) {
    $current = current($array);

    if (end($sorted) !== $current) {
        $sorted[] = $current;
        array_splice($array, key($array), 1);
    }

    $next = next($array);

    if (!$next) {
        reset($array);
        shuffle($array);
    }
}

print_r($sorted);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Retail
    [1] => Food
    [2] => Charity
    [3] => Entertainment
    [4] => Transport
    [5] => Entertainment
    [6] => Cosmetics
    [7] => Retail
)
```

Another input example:

```php
$array  = ['Retail', 'Retail', 'Retail', 'Retail', 'Retail', 'Food', 'Charity', 'Charity', 'Charity', 'Entertainment', 'Entertainment', 'Transport', 'Cosmetics'];
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Retail
    [1] => Food
    [2] => Retail
    [3] => Charity
    [4] => Retail
    [5] => Charity
    [6] => Retail
    [7] => Charity
    [8] => Entertainment
    [9] => Transport
    [10] => Entertainment
    [11] => Cosmetics
    [12] => Retail
)
```

Updated Code for special occasions like when input is like `['Retail', 'Retail', 'Food', 'Retail']` which in my case is plausible and acceptable:

```php
<?php

$array  = ['Retail', 'Retail', 'Food', 'Retail'];
$sorted = [];

$tries = 0;
$maxTries = count($array);

while (!empty($array) && $tries <= $maxTries) {
    $current = current($array);

    if (end($sorted) !== $current) {
        $sorted[] = $current;
        array_splice($array, key($array), 1);
    }

    $next = next($array);

    if (!$next) {
        reset($array);
        shuffle($array);
        $tries++;
    }
}

if (!empty($array)) {
    array_push($sorted, ...$array);
}

print_r($sorted);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Retail
    [1] => Food
    [2] => Retail
    [3] => Retail
)
```

Comment: That will create an endless loop, if your input data makes the required sorting impossible, such as f.e. `['Retail', 'Retail', 'Food', 'Retail']`

Comment: Shuffle should not be relied upon as an efficient/effective technique within an alogorithm.

Answer (score 0):

i tried keeping sorted array close to the input array.
first i remove any nonfitting elements from the array and try to insert them later.
if any elements are left i walk over the array, inserting them in any fitting position, avoiding endless loops. as result you get 2 arrays, one sorted and one where no fitting position could be found:

```
 $input =  ['Charity','Retail','Retail','Retail','Retail', 'Retail' ,'Retail',  'Charity',  'Charity', 'Charity','a' ];

$laRest     = [];
$sorted     = [];
$laNoPlace  = [];

while(count($input) >0) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($laRest); $i++) {
        if(isset($laRest[$i]) && $laRest[$i] != end($sorted)) {
            $sorted[] = $laRest[$i];
            unset($laRest[$i]);
        }
    }
    $laRest     = array_values($laRest);
    $lsElement  = array_shift($input);
    if (end($sorted) != $lsElement) {
        $sorted[] = $lsElement;
    }
    else {
        $laRest[] = $lsElement;
    }
}

if(count($laRest) >0) {
    while(count($laRest) >0) {
        $lsElement = array_shift($laRest);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($sorted); $i++) {
            if($i != 0 && $sorted[$i] != $lsElement && !isset($sorted[$i+1]) && $lsElement !='') {//end
                array_push($sorted, $lsElement);
                $lsElement = '';
            }
            if($i != 0 && $sorted[$i] != $lsElement && isset($sorted[$i+1]) && $sorted[$i+1] != $lsElement && $lsElement !='') {
                $lsStart = array_slice($sorted, 0, $i+1);
                $lsEnd   = array_slice($sorted , $i+1);
                $sorted  = array_merge($lsStart,  array($lsElement), $lsEnd);
                $lsElement = '';
            } 
            if($i == 0 && $sorted[$i] != $lsElement && $lsElement !='') {//start
              array_unshift($sorted, $lsElement);
              $lsElement = '';
            } 
        }
        if($lsElement != '') {
            $laNoPlace[] = $lsElement;
        }
    }
}

print_r($sorted);
echo "<HR>";
print_r($laNoPlace);
echo "<HR>";
```